# Overriding Built-in Classes (Python)

Tags: python, overriding, built-in

How can I view and override the full definition for built in classes? I have seen [the library docs](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) but am looking for something more.

For e.g. is it possible to override the Array Class such that the base index starts from 1 instead of 0, or to override `.sort()` of list to a sorting algorithm of my own liking?

Comment: Whether it's possible or not - would you really want to do that? I mean replace Array everywhere in Python with another one that works sufficiently differently that all the code everywhere in the Python libraries that uses Array will break?

Comment: I understand why you would want to develop your own MyArray class that works like a Ruby array, or whatever, but the poster was asking about replacing Python's Array class with his own, across the board.

Answer (score 6):

For creating your own `sort()` method, it's as simple as this:

```
class MyList(list):
    def sort(self):
       return 'custom sorting algorithm'

mylist = MyList([1,2,3])
mylist.sort() # => 'custom sorting algorithm'
```

I would NOT recommend changing the way lists are indexed as that goes against best practices, so I'm not even providing an example of that! Whenever you want to break convention for things like operator overloading or indexing, I feel that you should rethink why you want to do that and adapt to convention.

Comment: I can understand that it is not recommended... But I just wanted to know whether (and how) it could be done.

Comment: What you are looking for would be to overload `__getitem__` in your subclass: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Answer (score 4):

You *can* inherit from builtin types and override or add behaviour. If you *should* do this is an other question altogether. For an implementation of an n-based list (starting at 1 for example) [see this link](http://defcraft.blogspot.com/2007/04/n-based-python-list.html) (Array should be very similar).

For sort you can simply use the key function on `sorted`.